# Can I delete the old folders after updating JDK

Tags: java, windows, installation

Windows 8.1, JDK 1.8.0_25;

Everytime I update the JDK, it creates a new folder followed by version number in my installation path. After several times, now there're 4 of them, each takes more than 300MB disk space. What's inside seems to be the same except the version.

I wanna know, can I delete these old folders after updating ？

Now my installation path looks like this:(can't post image, lack of reputation)

C:\Program Files\Java

```
- jdk1.8.0_05    2014/7/5
- jdk1.8.0_11    2014/7/23
- jdk1.8.0_20    2014/9/1 
- jdk1.8.0_25    2014/10/19
- jre1.8.0_20    2014/10/19
- jre1.8.0_25    2014/10/19
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can delete everything except `- jdk1.8.0_25    2014/10/19` and `- jre1.8.0_25    2014/10/19`.

And don't forget to add `- jdk1.8.0_25/bin` to your `PATH` variable.

Comment: thx. I already modified the PATH. So every time my JDK got updated, I have to manually delete the old folder and update and PATH ? Any chance it can happen automatically. I might not remember to do so until I find problem in my code. @Aditya

Comment: no. coz you always download and install it. its always a separate exe/zip/tar file. that is always separate and irrelated to your previously installed jdk and jre